# VBA Error: "The object invoked has disconnected from its clients"

Tags: vba, excel

I am attempting to write a macro that matches up x/y coordinates to ellipses that they fit into. I get the automation error at the "Else" line in my code. I have reviewed a lot of other posts but I can't figure out what is wrong with my code. Any assistance is much appreciated. Thank you!

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Dim XR As Integer
Dim XC As Integer
Dim YR As Integer
Dim YC As Integer
Dim areaR As Integer
Dim areaC As Integer
Dim hR As Integer
Dim hC As Integer
Dim kR As Integer
Dim kC As Integer
Dim aR As Integer
Dim aC As Integer
Dim bR As Integer
Dim bC As Integer
Dim angleR As Integer
Dim angleC As Integer
Dim matchR As Integer
Dim matchC As Integer
XR = 2
XC = 1
YR = 2
YC = 2
Do Until ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(XR, XC).Value = ""
ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Activate
areaR = 2
areaC = 6
hR = 2
hC = 7
kR = 2
kC = 8
aR = 2
aC = 9
bR = 2
bC = 10
angleR = 2
angleC = 11
matchR = XR
matchC = 12
    Do Until ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(hR, hC).Value = ""
        If (((((ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(XR, XC).Value) _
             - (ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(hR, hC).Value)) * _
             Cos((ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(angleR, angleC).Value)) _
             + ((ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(YR, YC).Value) - _
             (ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(kR, kC).Value)) * Sin _
             ((ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(angleR, angleC).Value))) ^ 2) _
             / ((Cells(aR, aC).Value) ^ 2)) + (((((Cells(XR, XC).Value) - _
             (Cells(hR, hC).Value)) * Sin((ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Cells _
             (angleR, angleC).Value)) - ((ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(YR, YC).Value) _
             - (ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(kR, kC).Value)) _
             * Cos((Cells(angleR, angleC).Value))) ^ 2) / ((Cells(bR, bC).Value) ^ 2)) _
             <= 1 Then
             ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(matchR, matchC).Value = _
             ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(areaR, areaC)
       Else
             areaR = areaR + 1
             hR = hR + 1
             kR = kR + 1
             aR = aR + 1
             bR = bR + 1
             angleR = angleR + 1
       End If
    Loop
   XR = XR + 1
   YR = YR + 1
Loop
```

End Sub

Comment: Adding to @LimaNightHawk: You can also use the With statement to increase readability [http://www.excel-spreadsheet.com/vba/withendwith.htm]

Answer (score 0):

That's a lot of code, and doing direct math with cell reference values is very hard to read...probably even for you.

It may not be much of an answer, but if you create variables (yes, more variables), inside your loops, then your code will be easier to read for everyone and very possibly your error will emerge.

So instead of using `ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(XR, XC).Value` in your calculation, first do this: `X = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(XR, XC).Value`

But don't stop there. Include intermediate variable that will self-describe your code and the calculation process.

This will hopefully allow you to see  the code for what it really does.

```
isMatch = cosX <= 1
If isMatch Then
```

And, by the way, my suspission is that your error is coming from the fact that you are not qualifying *all* of your `Cells` methods with a sheets reference.